# Why the sprite is invisible after cloned?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I create a simple snake game. Clone the body section when snake eats an item. But new section appears invisible until next move. Can't figure out why.

In Inspector clone object has the same settings as prefab.
I also tried to set Order in Layer for sprites - didn't work.

[image]

[image]

```
    void Move () {
        if (_isAlive)
        {
            Vector2 currentPosition = transform.position;
            if (_previousDirection != _direction)
            {
                if (_direction == SnakeDirection.LEFT)
                {
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90);
                }
                else if (_direction == SnakeDirection.DOWN)
                {
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 180);
                }
                else if (_direction == SnakeDirection.RIGHT)
                {
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 270);
                }
                else if (_direction == SnakeDirection.UP)
                {
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
                }
                _previousDirection = _direction;
            }
            transform.Translate(0, 30, 0);
            CheckBorders();
            if (apple.IsEaten())
            {
                SnakeSection newSection = Instantiate(sectionPrefab);
                newSection.transform.position = currentPosition;
                newSection.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
                _tail.Insert(0, newSection);
                apple.SetEaten(false);
            } else if (_tail.Count > 0)
            {
                _tail.Last().transform.position = currentPosition;
                _tail.Insert(0, _tail.Last());
                _tail.RemoveAt(_tail.Count - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice you're using SpriteRenderer and Image component at the-same on one GameObject. Why is that? You should only go with one of them....

Comment: @Programmer is tried the Order in layer option, SpriteRendered has it. Left only Image component for all sections.

Comment: Have you checked if the position is correct in the frame it's instantiated? Couldn't it be over another body part, in the wrong tile?

Comment: @NathaliaSoragge you're right. Found it on wrong position. Could you post this answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're setting the wrong position when instantiating. Check if it's not over another body sprite in the wrong tile.